# How to get last version of build in Nexus repository?

Tags: typescript, npm, nexus, package.json

I have [Nexus repository](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-pro).
In my project in package.json I use:

```
"my-card-web": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/repository/npm-releases/my-card-web/-/my-card-web-1.0.0.tgz
```

I always change version manually.
How can I set last version of build in package.json (instead of 1.0.0)?

For example, it should be something like:

```
"my-card-web": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/repository/npm-releases/my-card-web/-/my-card-web-#LATEST_VERSION#.tgz
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: this is generally not recommended because it causes non-reproducible builds. If you really have to, what stops you from putting my-card-web-latest.tgz on the nexus repository and just reference that by URL?

Comment: @Clashsoft yes, we develop "my-card-web" too and it's too complicated to change version of each build in package.json every day. Maybe we can write something like ""my-card-web": ".../my-card-web-#LATEST_VERSION#.tgz"

Comment: Every day? How often do you release new versions of the library (?) It sounds like instead of the syntax, you actually need a better release cadence or a monorepo.

Comment: The problem with "#LATEST_VERSION#" is that npm does not know how to get the latest version. For regular "package": "^1.2.3" at least it knows to look up the manifest on npmjs.com, but for any other URL there is no way to know. There is however custom registry support, maybe you can look into that: https://gist.github.com/shirakaba/d4bc52330aecc2fcb20d15a29b2927e1